# dailymotion video api, created_time returns not correct

Tags: java, date, dailymotion-api

I made an api request:

```
https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=channel,channel.name,created_time,duration,id,owner,owner.avatar_240_url,owner.avatar_480_url,owner.screenname,owner.username,thumbnail_240_url,thumbnail_480_url,thumbnail_720_url,title,views_total&list=what-to-watch&limit=12&page=1
```

But the `created_time` value seems error, it's something like `1487308049`, which translated to a `Java Date` is `Sunday, January 18, 1970 5:08:28 AM UTC`. This cannot be correct, right?

The `created_time` value should be `Long`, and much much bigger than something like `1487308049`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Java to parse the created_time from DailyMotion API result.
In Java, date is measured in milliseconds while in some other languages(read PHP), it is in seconds. The create_time value you are getting is in seconds. You just need append 3 zeroes at the end to convert it into millisceonds before converting it to date

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1487308049L);      
System.out.println("DateTime: " + dateTime);

//DateTime: 1970-01-18T10:38:28.049+05:30

DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(1487308049000L);      
System.out.println("DateTime: " + dateTime2); 

//DateTime: 2017-02-17T10:37:29.000+05:30
```

Hope this helps